# Where do the Linux kernel router code replace the MAC address

Tags: linux, networking

The router will replace the source MAC address of the package it received with the address of the previous hop and the destination MAC address with the address of next hop.

The linux provides a functionality to worked as a router. My question is how the kernel code implement the function for mac address update during its package forwarding process? And where is this part of code

I try to find the codes in /net/ipv4, but can not found anything...

Comment: My understanding is that on some cards, software doesn't directly control the MAC on outgoing packets.  i.e., you can set it in ifconfig but for such a card it's not the kernel inserting the MAC.  So it seems even if there is such a place it wouldn't always get used.

Comment: But I still think there should be someplace the kernel code change the content of the package. An linux machine can also act as a bridge, and in that case the mac address forward/transmit by the machine does not change. In the router case, it is been changed, so I think there should be someplace the kernel can choose to update the package or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not what actually happens.

IP is not dependent on ethernet, so what happens is dependent upon the underlying protocol of the lower layer.

The same thing happens if it is a locally-originated IP packet, or if it is one which has been routed for another host.

Linux's IPv4 stack is not ethernet-dependent in any way, in fact lots of other link-layer protocols are supported by the kernel. IP being a WAN protocol, you can route between different underlying protocols. Some examples are

- ppp, slip (serial lines)
- PPTP, GRE (for tunnels, mostly VPNs)
- IP over ATM
- Token ring (mostly legacy, I think)
- Loopback and dummy (for local communication only)
- Wifi (although this is actually mostly identical to ethernet)

So what actually happens when routing IP frames from one ethernet interface to another is that the link-layer is stripped off completely, then a new link-layer is formed after routing. If the protocol were not ethernet, an appropriate link-layer packet for that protocol would be used instead.

So nobody "changes the MAC address", but rather, the link-layer packet is just completely rebuilt.

Comment: Well, then would you mind tell me where can I found the code in that the linux kernel rebuild the new link-layer frame/package header? Because my goal is try to find someway to keep a package's MAC address unchanged when it is been forward by a linux router, and the only way I can came out is to find the code that build this new link-layer head and change its behavior..

Comment: My impression is that it's hardware-specific and hence each device driver does it differently. Some devices may write some of the headers in hardware.